# Delayed Response and Call Dequeue in Twilio FastAPI Application with OpenAI Content Generation

Tags: async-await, twilio, fastapi, twilio-twiml

I am building a Twilio application in FAST API that uses OpenAI to generate content for incoming call requests. The idea is to put the caller on hold with hold music using the Twilio Enqueue verb while waiting for the content to be generated by OpenAI. This is because content generated by openai API can take more than 15 seconds. And if twilio does not receive response within 15 seconds, it gives read time out error. Once the content is ready, I want to dequeue the call and use the Twilio Say verb to speak the generated completion to the caller. I am not sure how to do that when a completion is generated.
Hence, I need a solution that allows me to dequeue the call once the content generation is completed.

I would appreciate any guidance or examples on how to achieve this delayed response other than holding the call and use the Say verb to speak the completion generated by openai to the caller.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
import openai
import asyncio
import logging
import os

app = FastAPI()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

async def execute_task():
    openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    completion = ''
    async for chunk in await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Generate an article on sports"
        }],
        stream=True,
    ):
        content = chunk["choices"][0].get("delta", {}).get("content")
        if content is not None:
            completion = completion + content
    logging.info(completion)

# Route to receive incoming call requests from Twilio
@app.post("/incoming_call")
async def incoming_call():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    task = asyncio.create_task(execute_task())
    # Use the <Enqueue> verb to put the caller on hold with hold music    
    response.enqueue("support")
    return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

# Route to initiate the call from Twilio
@app.get("/make_call")
async def make_call():
    account_sid = os.environ.get("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")
    auth_token = os.environ.get("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")
    to_phone = os.environ.get("TWILIO_TO_PHONE")
    from_phone = os.environ.get("TWILIO_FROM_PHONE")
    ngrok_url = "https://your-new-ngrok-url.example.com"  # Replace with your new ngrok URL

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    call = client.calls.create(
        url=f'{ngrok_url}/incoming_call',
        to=to_phone,
        from_=from_phone
    )
    return {"message": "Call initiated!"}
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired behavior of dequeuing the call and using the Twilio `Say` verb to speak the generated completion to the caller, you can follow these steps:

1. Modify the `execute_task` function to return the completed content.
2. Use a separate route to handle the completion and dequeue the call.
3. Modify the `incoming_call` route to enqueue the call and initiate the content generation task.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Enqueue, Say
from twilio.rest import Client
import openai
import asyncio
import logging
import os

app = FastAPI()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

async def generate_content():
    openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    completion = ''
    async for chunk in await openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Generate an article on sports"
        }],
        stream=True,
    ):
        content = chunk["choices"][0].get("message", {}).get("content")
        if content is not None:
            completion = completion + content
    return completion

@app.post("/incoming_call")
async def incoming_call():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    # Enqueue the call with hold music
    with response.enqueue("support") as enqueue_node:
        enqueue_node.play("http://your-hold-music-url.example.com")

    return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

@app.post("/handle_completion")
async def handle_completion(completion: str):
    response = VoiceResponse()
    # Dequeue the call
    response.enqueue("completed")
    # Use the Say verb to speak the generated completion to the caller
    response.say(completion, voice="alice", language="en-US")

    return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

@app.get("/make_call")
async def make_call():
    account_sid = os.environ.get("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")
    auth_token = os.environ.get("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")
    to_phone = os.environ.get("TWILIO_TO_PHONE")
    from_phone = os.environ.get("TWILIO_FROM_PHONE")
    ngrok_url = "https://your-new-ngrok-url.example.com"  # Replace with your new ngrok URL

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    call = client.calls.create(
        url=f'{ngrok_url}/incoming_call',
        to=to_phone,
        from_=from_phone
    )
    return {"message": "Call initiated!"}
```

In this, I've introduced a new route `/handle_completion` to handle the completion from OpenAI. Once the content is generated, you can use this route to dequeue the call and use the `Say` verb to speak the generated completion to the caller.

Please make sure to replace `"http://your-hold-music-url.example.com"` with the actual URL of your hold music and adjust other URLs and parameters according to your setup. This example should give you a foundation to build upon for your Twilio and OpenAI integration.

this is the example code for you to understand more.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
import openai
import asyncio
import logging
import os

app = FastAPI()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Simulate generating content from OpenAI (replace with actual OpenAI API call)
async def simulate_openai_completion():
    generated_content = "This is a simulated generated content from OpenAI."
    return generated_content

# Step 1: Define the /handle_completion route to handle the generated completion
@app.post("/handle_completion")
async def handle_completion(completion: str):
    response = VoiceResponse()

    # Step 2: Dequeue the call using the <Enqueue> verb with a dequeue instruction
    # This instructs Twilio to dequeue the call from the "support" queue
    response.enqueue("completed")

    # Step 3: Use the <Say> verb to speak the generated completion to the caller
    response.say(completion, voice="alice", language="en-US")

    # Step 4: Return the TwiML response as an XML
    return Response(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

# Example: Using the /simulate_and_handle_completion route
@app.post("/simulate_and_handle_completion")
async def simulate_and_handle_completion():
    # Simulate generating content from OpenAI (replace with actual OpenAI API call)
    generated_content = await simulate_openai_completion()

    # Call the /handle_completion route and pass the generated content
    response = await handle_completion(generated_content)

    return response

# ...
# Other route definitions, Twilio setup, and environment variables
# ...

# Assume the rest of your FastAPI application setup
# ...
```